# how to check if a line contains text and then stop after it reaches a blank line? [Python]

Tags: python, file, txt

am writing this algorithm that takes strings from a text file and appends them to an array. if the strings are in continuous line ex.

```
ABCD
EFG
HIJK
LMNOP
```

then they would be appended into the same array until it reaches a blank line at which point it stops and starts appending the next number of continuous arrays to a different array.

In my head a for loop is the way to go as i have the number of lines but i am just not sure how to check if a line has ANY TYPE of text or not (Not looking for any substrings just checking if the line itself contains anything).

Comment: An empty or blank line will end with an EOL end of line character. `\n`. Further, is will have a length of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the current line equal the new line character.

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n':
            print('Empty line')
        else:
            print('line contain string')
```

Comment: thank you much, this made me feel like an idiot haha, dont know why i didnt think of it that way. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're stripping the linebreak off each line, you can just check afterward to see if the result is empty.  Given the following file `text.txt`:

```
ABCD
EFG
HIJK
LMNOP

QRSTUV
WXYZ
```

here's an example of reading it into a list of lists of strings:

```
>>> arr = [[]]
>>> with open("text.txt") as f:
...     for line in f:
...         line = line.strip()
...         if line:
...             arr[-1].append(line)
...         else:
...             arr.append([])
...
>>> arr
[['ABCD', 'EFG', 'HIJK', 'LMNOP'], ['QRSTUV', 'WXYZ']]
```